# Correlate continuous data with dichotomous data, with correction for an ordinal variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, spss

I want to study association b/w continuous data (age) and dichotomous data (complication: yes/no), with "correction" for an ordinal variable (intra-operative nerve laesion).

I have a database of 427 patients, of whom 50 have suffered a post operative complication (altered sensation). 
The goal of this research is *to analyse the influence* of "age at operation" on the chance of the postoperative complication "altered sensation". "Intra-operative nerve laesion" was scored (0/1/2/3/4/5) and is an imported factor influencing "altered sensation". So this must be included in the analysis.

Hopefully somebody could help me with this analysis in SPSS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may safely take your "ordinal" variable as equi-interval one, like age, and do **binary logistic regression** with these two as the predictors ("covariates"). Or, if you want to transform your ordinal variable "optimally" nonlinearly into an interval one, you can do **optimal scaling regression** (CATREG) first, save the transformed predictor and then do the logistic regression.